# How do I insert parameters into the URL with $stateProvider?

Tags: angularjs

Here's my code:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('game.wordSearch', {
        url: "/wordSearch/:index/",

        template: wordSearchTemplate,

        controller: function($stateParams){

            app.wordSearchIndex=$stateParams.index}})
```

So, if I type in `www.mysite.com/wordSearch/14` into the URL bar, then it works showing me the word search with an index of 14. Now I have to figure out how to navigate to this from a different view on my website.

On my site, there are a bunch of boxes and if you click one it tells javascript what game you want with the global variable wordSearchIndex. But if I navigate to the page on my app, I only know how to change the state to `game.wordSearch`. I don't know how to call this state and tell it to put `wordSearchIndex` as the parameter for `:index`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do that to navigate:

```
 $state.go('game.wordSearch', { index: wordSearchIndex});
```